# JTDS driver not working for Sql Server 2008R2 and Denali Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, jtds

I am trying to connect Sql Server Data Base using windows authentication from my application using JTDS driver but i got following error

> SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not
>   loaded. Check the java.library.path
>   system property.

Following are the scenarios where i tried to resolve but still something is missing..

1. i have added ntlmauth.dll in system directory and it works fine for Sql server 2005.
2. But the same thing i tried for Sql Server 2008 R2 and Denali but it gives me the same error as i mentioned above
3. Also i considered bit i mean i copied ntlmauth.dll from x64\SSO\ path in system directory.

I an confused why this is not working for Sql Server 2008 R2 and Denali.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try by placing the `ntlmauth.dll` file in the `bin` folder of your Java Runtime Environment (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin`).

Be sure to match the "bitness" (32 bit or 64 bit) of the DLL with the JVM bitness.

I ran into the same issue using SQL Server Express 2008 R2 and this [MSDN SQL Server Forum Article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqldatabaseengine/thread/fd649f47-4551-419f-a487-c3e28ba1be48) recommended this resolution, which worked for me.

Comment: One easy thing to miss is if there is a mismatch between the word size of the JVM and the library. So if you are running a 32-bit Java and have a 64-bit DLL, then it will not load.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from putting it into your JRE directly, you can also just specify the `java.library.path` as such:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\jtds-1.3.1-dist\x64\SSO
```

The above directory would then contain the `ntlmauth.dll` file

Answer (score 0):

In addition to DeChrist's response, I had to add the same dll file in the `bin` folder of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\bin` also. In that case, it worked for me.

Comment: This to me looks more like a comment than a complete answer.

Comment: I tried to do a comment but I don't have _enough reputation_ yet. As I see, I only can do it in my own answers at the moment.